# profiling a linux command to get metrics

Tags: linux, centos, profiling

I am trying to unzip a huge .gz file. I would like to know if there is a way we could profile this command to get the CPU utilization while the command is executing

I am looking for something like this

```
gunzip file.gz | profileTheCommand
```

Comment: Did you try with the `time` keyword?

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you for the pointer. I will use time.

Answer (score 2):

Piping the output of `gunzip` to a profiling tool won't get you very far because `gunzip` doesn't output much runtime information.

You can use standard linux profiling tools, however, like `perf`. Check out the tutorial at https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial

For example, here is profile stats for untaring a ~100 MB file:

```
$ perf stat -B tar xJf ghc-8.0.2-x86_64-deb8-linux.tar.xz 

 Performance counter stats for 'tar xJf ghc-8.0.2-x86_64-deb8-linux.tar.xz':

      14959.293532      task-clock (msec)         #    0.737 CPUs utilized          
            340822      context-switches          #    0.023 M/sec                  
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
              2401      page-faults               #    0.161 K/sec                  
   <not supported>      cycles                                                      
   <not supported>      instructions                                                
   <not supported>      branches                                                    
   <not supported>      branch-misses                                               

      20.299894777 seconds time elapsed
```

Depending on your kernel version you may see slightly different output. Also note that `perf` may not be compiled to understand all the events going on in your particular CPU. That's what the `<not supported>` messages above are about.

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck will probably be reading/writing, not CPU. Anyway, time(1) should tell.